# Cron jobs terminate prematurely on amazon ec2 crontab

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, server, cron

I am using amazon ec2 server and I have set up some cron jobs on crontab.

Sample for setting up cron job

```
58 11 12 * * php /var/www/html/folder/index.php controller/function/parameter
```

When I try

> crontab -l

on putty they all appear and everything seems to be working fine.

But cron jobs with lengthy execution time tend to stop prematurely without generating any error in log file.

I am also setting the large execution time at the top of my php script

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600000);
```

I couldn't figure out whats happening. Any kind of help will be appreciated.