# Setting up cron jobs on AWS EC2 via crontab

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

i am trying to set up a cron job on one of my EC2 instances on AWS via crontab. Doing following steps:

- Log into my server via ssh (with user `ec2-user`) and running `crontab
  -l` to check if any crontabs are running for existing users. There isn't any.
- Run nano `crontab -e` to create a new crontab file for `ec2-user`. File created and saved. When running `crontab -l` getting output `no crontab file for ec2-user` and obviously `cron` is not running.

When running `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep cron` seem to be running ok. Output is:

> root      2460     1  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 crond

I have had a look into a few resource on the web:

- [Setting Cron Job in AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501599/setting-cron-job-in-aws-ec2-instance)
- [Cron jobs terminate prematurely on amazon ec2 crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776164/cron-jobs-terminate-prematurely-on-amazon-ec2-crontab)

But still not working. Seems like something is wrong when creating a crontab file for `ec2-user` but i cannot seem to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: You need to run `crontab -e`....then you need to write your cron instructions, then press `Escape` then `:` and write `wq`(for `write` and `quit`)...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Hackerman. Just done that and all seem to worked fine - got the message "crontab installed". But the job still does not run for some reason. And when i do crontab -l i'm not getting anything back at the moment. Not quite sure what to do now. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason when i add my cron job */5 * * * * php /var/www/html/scheduled.php > /dev/null 2>&1 - the first "*" is not getting populated. Might this be the reason?

Comment: So the job is not running? Try to redirect stdout and stderr to a file, like: /5 * * * * php /var/www/html/scheduled.php >> ~/tmp.log 2>&1 and check if there is some kind of error.

Comment: Hello Danilo, thanks for your help. So i should just update my crop job to look like this: */5 * * * * php /var/www/html/scheduled.php >> ~/tmp.log 2>&1 and it will create a log with any errors. I am wondering if there is any other way for me to check if my cron is set up correctly

Comment: btw my full command looks like this */5 * * * * usr/bin/php /var/www/html/scheduled.php > /dev/null 2>&1 - i am not sure is adding usr/bin/ in front of php will make any difference. Also, i am not sure is cron functionality is running on the server for ec2-user at the first place

Comment: just ran service --status-all and it seem that cron is not running as i was not able to locate it in the list of services. Is there a way to launch it?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to add cron file (any name without dot, e.g. my-cron-job)
the content is just the cron command
make sure there is \r in the end of the command
add this file under /etc/cron.d
permissions 644

This approach is used in all automations in Ansible / Puppet